Docker push is not Overwriting image with latest changes when using same TAG
Docker is not updating the image when using the same tag. In fact, when I set a fresh new tag in the github action such as TAG=latestV1, it turns out to build the image with the latest changes. Nevertheless, when using again the same latestV1 tag, the latest changes are not built in the image!!
I was thinking on using each github commit hash as the tag to address this issue. However, I will need to take care of deleting old images from the docker hub. I believe it shouldn't be necessary to follow those extra steps. I just want to figure how can I override the image using the same tag with my latest changes.
My build job:
build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout source
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          ref: main
      - name: Login to docker hub
        run: echo "${{secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD}}" | docker login -u ${{secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME}} --password-stdin
      - name: Build, tag and Push Images
        run: |
          REPO=${{secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME}}/****
          TAG=latest
          docker build --no-cache -t $REPO:client-$TAG --build-arg NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL=${{secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}} --build-arg NEXT_PUBLIC_KEY_USER_SESSION=${{secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEY_USER_SESSION}} ./frontend
          docker build --no-cache -t $REPO:server-$TAG ./backend
          docker build --no-cache -t $REPO:nginx-$TAG ./proxy

          docker push $REPO:client-$TAG
          docker push $REPO:server-$TAG
          docker push $REPO:nginx-$TAG

This is the deploy job:
  deploy:
    needs: build
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: self-hosted
      - name: ...

      - name: Stop existing containers
        run: docker-compose down
      - name: Run container with Docker Compose
        run: docker-compose up -d


(Particularly in environments like Kubernetes, using something like a commit hash as an image tag is usually a good idea, even if it results in many images.  For Kubernetes specifically, if the image name doesn't change then it assumes the cluster is up-to-date.  Using a unique tag per image ensures that you'll obviously need to pull and redeploy on update, and it makes it easier to roll back when you need to.)

The missing step was pulling images from the docker hub. Thus, I decided to update the docker-compose down as following to remove all local images stored in my aws ec2 instance:
docker-compose down --rmi all

This way the up command can pull up new images.
